# Transformations with DataFrame exporting series

Tags: python, pandas, series, dataframe

I have data in the following form stored in a DataFrame. I would like to get daily sums for each of the metrics grouped by their type, so for example total sum for linkedin_profiles on October 3rd 2012.

```
sample_date                            metric_name  sample

2012-10-03 21:30:18.742307+00:00  linkedin_profile     257
2012-10-03 21:30:25.132189+00:00   twitter_profile     972
2012-10-03 21:30:26.063389+00:00     youtube_video   10393
2012-10-03 21:30:26.178347+00:00     youtube_video    2866
2012-10-03 21:30:26.215093+00:00     youtube_video    5877
```

I would also potentially like to be able to extract metric_name specific data into a Series object for each of (metric_name) from the DataFrame. i.e so it would be daily sums for one metric like linkedin_profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have this DataFrame:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = '''\
sample_date                            metric_name  sample
2012-10-03 21:30:18.742307+00:00  linkedin_profile     257
2012-10-03 21:30:25.132189+00:00   twitter_profile     972
2012-10-03 21:30:26.063389+00:00     youtube_video   10393
2012-10-03 21:30:26.178347+00:00     youtube_video    2866
2012-10-03 21:30:26.215093+00:00     youtube_video    5877
'''        
df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0,1])
```

You could group by the date and metric_name and then sum the `sample` values like this:

```
dates = df['sample_date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
total = df.groupby([dates, 'metric_name']).sum()
print(total)
#                               sample
# sample_date metric_name             
# 2012-10-03  linkedin_profile     257
#             twitter_profile      972
#             youtube_video      19136
```

Or, if you wish to first select only those rows with `metric_name` equal to `'youtube_video'`, you could use

```
youtube_df = (df[df['metric_name'] == 'youtube_video'])
```

and then groupby dates like this:

```
dates = youtube_df['sample_date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
youtube_total = youtube_df.groupby([dates]).sum()
print(youtube_total)
# sample_date        
# 2012-10-03    19136
```

Comment: FWIW I often use `sep=r"\s\s+"` rather than `widths` when (as here) it can be avoided.  (Of course without seeing the full data it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: @unutbu is the youtube_total a series object? if not how can I convert it to series object.

Comment: The columns of a DataFrame are Series. So you could use `youtube_total = youtube_total['sample']` to make it a Series.